# is mod_perl required for mod_include to work?

Tags: apache-httpd

I recall when enabling server-side-includes in Apache, it didn't work until I installed mod_perl when I was using Ubuntu.

Now I'm trying to enable it on Mac OS X, but I don't see a mod_perl file anywhere. So I'm wondering - is the server side includes module (mod_include I believe) is standalone or does it depends on mod_perl being installed too?

**edit**: I was able to enable includes on mac OS X without doing any additional module installation, but I can't remember if this because mod_perl was unneeded or whether it was already there. Man, I wish I had a better memory.